# Issue concerning path input in .bat menu

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi I am trying to make a small menu in which the .bat file uses the user input to define a path. The code below works.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P var= Type The FULL Path In Here:
MKDIR %var%\
pause
```

However when I try to implement the code into the menu below. It fails and I can't read the error because it immediately exits the batch file. I am running a windows 10 machine and running the batch from the C:\ drive. The batch file makes the folders on the C:\ drive as well. I would be grateful for any help Thanks.

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO  ...............................................
ECHO  PRESS 1 to select your task, or 2 TO EXIT.
ECHO  ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO  1 - Set Path
ECHO.
ECHO  2 - EXIT
ECHO.
SET /P M=Type 1 or 5 then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO CallScript1
IF %M%==5 GOTO EOF

CallScript1
@ECHO OFF
SET /P var= Type The FULL Path In Here:
MKDIR %var%\
GOTO:EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the colon before the label CallScript1 on line 17
i.e. replace

CallScript1

with

:CallScript1

Comment: Moreover, note the difference `GOTO EOF` vs. `GOTO :EOF`. Read and follow [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php). And what-if somebody replies e.g. `88` to `SET /P` or even hits only `Enter`?

Comment: Thanks JosefZ i'll be sure to check it out XD